# Excel data validation list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to have a formula assigned to data validation list in Excel? For example if you have "Sum" in the drop down list, it should be able to have the sum  formula linked to the cells.

[image]

Comment: Actually there are several ratios in the data validation, the idea is the link the relevant formula to each ratios. If there is a easy way of doing this would be great otherwise, can consider VBA? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Validation list is small then we can make a use of nested if -

e.g.

```
=if(validation_List="Sum",sum(A1:A2),if(validation_List="average",average(A1:A2)))
```

Comment: Or use `CHOICE(MATCH(chosen_formula, list_formula,0),SUM(A1:A2),AVERAGE(A1:A2),...)` in combination with named range *list_formula* if you have longer validation lists and want to keep the formula readable.